# sqlite query question

Tags: sqlite

i'm messing around with sqlite. i've never messed with query languages or databases before. i made a little test database. it's a account database with accounts and id's. if i do the following, i get the max value:

```
SELECT MAX(balance)
FROM accounts
```

but how can i print ONLY the id of the account with the max balance?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id 
FROM accounts
WHERE balance = (SELECT MAX(balance) from accounts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?:

```
SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE balance = MAX(balance)
```

Comment: i tried something like that. i get an error: misuse of aggregate function MAX(). i just tried what you replied with as well. same error.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
    SELECT id FROM accounts ORDER BY balance DESC LIMIT 1;
```